# Eclipse and intelliJ android SDK questions

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have previously installed `intelliJ 13` and `android SDK` and configured correctly. Now I downloaded `Eclipse` with built-in `ADT`(in that with all default components), which also includes essential `Android SDK` components (`API 19`). When I opened `AVD Manager` in `Eclipse`, it showed the `AVDs` that I created previously when using `intelliJ`. I opened the `SDK Manager` in `Eclipse` folder, and it showed that

[image]

Although I can see in `Eclipse`

[image]

My question is whether `Eclipse` and `intelliJ` shared the same `ADT Manager` source folder and why the `Android SDK Manager` in `Eclipse` showed that components in `API19` are not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Project Structure dialog `File | Project Structure` in IntelliJ you will be able to view Platform SDK settings. Check to see if the paths are the same for both IDEs

Comment: Because I can't find `ADT Manager` in `Eclipse` folder, so I wonder are `Eclipse` and `intelliJ` share the same `ADT Manager`

Comment: I believe that Android Eclipse Bundle comes bundled with ADT manager. It's been a while since i've used the Eclipse Android bundle. I believe that IntelliJ relies on you to install the ADT tools on your own. My guess is that you have two instances of the ADT manager, and that Eclipse is using the manager that it came bundled with, and IntelliJ is using the ADT manager that was downloaded from the google developer page. In any case i suggest that you set both SDK paths to the same directory in IntelliJ and Eclipse, to avoid having duplicate SDK files.